# Scipy curve_fit does not estimate offset parameter but works great for other needed parameters

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I don't know if this is a problem related to my objective function or Scipy's curve_fit library because most of the posts with a similar problem usually have something wrong with their objective function.
Problem statement:
I am trying to fit a gamma function with 4 parameters namely: time to peak (tmax), max amplitude(ymax), shape(b) and offset. curve_fit is estimating reliable results for the first 3 parameters but returns the initial guess for offset.
My initial guess is p0 = [231, 5, 0.006,60]
and the plot looks like this:
[Plot of initial guess of parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpFYD.png)

However, when I run it on data, the offset value is always 60 or whatever the initial guess is set as whereas the other 3 parameters are giving reliable results.

My objective function is:

```
def objective2(t,tmax, ymax, b, offset):
    offInt = math.ceil(offset)
    offArr = np.zeros(offInt).astype(dtype=np.float32)
    offArr = np.append(offArr,ymax*((t[:(len(t)-offInt)]/tmax)*np.exp((b*tmax)))* 2.713*np.exp((tmax-t[:(len(t)-offInt)])*b))
    return offArr
```

where t = np.arange(1,887,1).astype(dtype=np.float32)

Can someone help me understand where things are going south?

Thanks.

Comment: That is due to the `ceil` function. For small variations of `offset` there is no change in your objective function and, hence, the according derivative is zero -> no change.

Comment: I suggest that you have a look at something like: "fitting integer valued functions"

Comment: My data is supposed to give a varied range of offsets ~(60-100), ceil would estimated values near 100 as 100 right?

Comment: Sure, `ceil(99.5)` would be `100` but what is `d/dx ceil(x)` or even worse, the numerical derivative done by `curve_fit()`, i.e. `( ceil( a + delta ) - ceil( a ) ) / delta`. which, for small `delta` is likely to be zero, always.

Comment: My typical trick would be: Introduce a soft step. Iterate the fitting process, gradually making the step more sharp.